# How to detect lines from image and remove in c# using image processor api?

Tags: c#, image

I have code as follows. This is sample image from which is  have to remove dark lines and save to new location.In this code didnt found any error but i didnt get acutal result.

```
  private static void RemoveLines(MagickImage original, MagickImage image, string geometryValue)
    {
        image.Scale(new MagickGeometry(geometryValue));
        MagickGeometry geometry = new MagickGeometry(original.Width, original.Height);
        geometry.IgnoreAspectRatio = true;
        image.Scale(geometry);

        image.AutoLevel();
        image.Shave(20, 20);
        image.Despeckle();
        image.ReduceNoise();

        image.Morphology(MorphologyMethod.Erode, Kernel.Diamond, 2);
        using (MagickImage clone = image.Clone())
        {
            image.Negate(); 
            image.Composite(original, Gravity.Center);                
        }           
    }

    public static void RemoveLines(string filePath)
    {
        using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(filePath)) // image001.tif
        {
            image.RePage(); // +repage
            image.RemoveArtifact(filePath);
            using (MagickImage original = image.Clone())
            {
                using (MagickImage firstClone = original.Clone()) // -clone 0
                {
                    RemoveLines(original, firstClone, "x1!"); // -scale x1!
                    using (MagickImage secondClone = firstClone.Clone()) // -clone 0
                    {
                        RemoveLines(secondClone, firstClone, "1x!"); // -scale x1!
                        firstClone.Write(@"C:\a\result2.tiff");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use Images if not really necessary. External sources can disappear and your question would be broken. Paste your code into the question, so others can copy it and figure things out on their own.